# Why is the DIV misplaced when the window is minimized?

Tags: html, css, margin

When the window is minimized, everything remains intact but not the navigation.

[image]

The image below is when the window is maximized and the image above when the window is minimized.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>

        <nav>
          <div class="navigation">

                <a href="home.html">
                    <div class="box" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)">
                        <img src="images/home.png">
                     <div class="name" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)">HOME</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/aboutus.png">
                    <div class="name">ABOUT US</div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/groupcompanies.png">
                    <div class="name">GROUP OF COMPANIES</div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/career.png">
                    <div class="name">CAREER</div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/contactus.png">
                    <div class="name">CONTACT US</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>    

</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url(images/pattern.png);
    min-width: 775px;
    overflow:auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"myfont";
    src:url(font/PTN57F.woff);
}
.header {
    max-width:1200px;
    min-width:200px;
    height:170px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius:3px;

}

.logo {
    width:230px;
}

.logo img {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:31px;
    border-right:solid  #FFF 1px;
    padding-right:33px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}


.navigation {
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:256px;
    float:none;

}

.box {
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:left;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin-top:31px;

}

.box:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
}
.name {
    height:23px;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:myfont;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.box img {

    float:none;
    margin-left:38px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
```

Comment: Have you applied any css to `.navigation` as the css you posted doesn't contain any code for it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @InsaneCoder '.navigation {
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:256px;
    float:none;

}'

Comment: @AnaMaria If you have seen the picture. When I minimize the window and scroll to right, the nagivation is misplaced and comes out of the header.

Comment: @user2153953 That's still not a question.

Comment: @user2153953 :One possible reason is that you have given `margin-left:256px` which is from browser's left side.Try to give navigation's position relative to the immediate external container

Comment: @MiniRagnarok : The question is clear : that the navigation gets displaced when browser window is maximized again after minimization.

Comment: Ok I will ask like this, is there a way that my header gets fixed and doesn't gets smaller when i minimize the window, because that's what happening too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boxes are inside `div.navigation`, which has a left margin of `256px`. When the `div.header` resizes, the left margin stays the same. If you want the `navigation` centered inside the `header` you can use

```
.navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This way it will not overflow the header div and adjust the left margin according to the overall width.

As of your comment, if you want the `header` stay the same, you must give it a fixed width, like

```
.header {
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Then, you also don't need the `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear but I have figured it out. There was something wrong with my body min width. Thank you @olaf.